# Use tickPositioner with data loaded via ajax?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to use Highchart's tickPositioner method to load tick positions via ajax so I can use some already existing logic to do the calculations. It does not seem to be waiting for the tickPositioner method to actually return data though. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

My actual code:

```
tickPositioner: function(min, max) {
    $.getJSON('/fred2/graph/ajax-requests.php?action=gtp', {min: min, max: max}, function(data) {
        console.log(data.tick_positions);
        return data.tick_positions;
    });
}
```

A JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/TWTZh/

Comment: Why would it wait?  The AJAX call by definition is asynchronous. You should just create the chart in your `$.getJSON` success callback and pass the tick positions via `tickPositions` array (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositions)

Comment: I tried setting async to false but it didn't make a difference. Setting a static array won't work because series can be added/removed dynamically.

Comment: I think this is bad idea to get tick positions from AJAX. For me as user it would be terrible to wait each time when hide/show something in legend, or to zoom in/out or even resize window.. I advice to move your logic to front-end and there calculate tick positions.